# How to add firebase collection data to List of object in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i currently have a constructor class named Product

```
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title, description;
  final List<String> images;
  final List<Color> colors;
  final double rating, price;
  bool isFavorite, isPopular;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.images,
    required this.colors,
    this.rating = 0.0,
    this.isFavorite = false,
    this.isPopular = false,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.description,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "id": id,
      "name": title,
      "description": description,
      "price": price,
      "rating": rating,
      "images": images,
      "isPopular": isPopular,
      "isFavorite": isFavorite,
    };
  }
}
```

My products are saved in the collection named 'products'.

```
final CollectionReference _productRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');
```

I want to add the collection data in a list. But any of you have an idea how to do that?
Im using List because i used ...List.generate to show each product of the list

```
List<Product> products = [
// Insert here
];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

add factory constructor named fromDoc (or any name you want) to Product Object

Example:

```
factory Product.fromDoc(productDocumentFromFirebase) {
    return Product(
            //fill in the fields
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.get("name"),
         )
}
```

**Step 2**

get list of data from firebase as a dynamic list

```
var dataFromFirebase = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').get();

List productsDocuments = dataFromFirebase.docs;
```

**Step 3**

map this dynamic list of data to Product objects

```
List<Product> products = productsDocuments.map((productDoc) => Product.fromDoc(productDoc)).toList();
```

And that's it. Now you have list of product objects.